# Programmatically assess relationship between type variables in class hierarchy

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose I have a Java class hierarchy defined as follow:

```
interface Bar<T> {}

class Foo<A,B> implements Bar<B> {}
```

How can I programmatically assess (using reflection) that the type parameter of Bar in Foo is the second of foo's parameters and not the first (B instead of A)?

I've tried using `TypeVariable#getName()` in order to compare the names, but when I apply `getGenericInterfaces()` to `Foo<A,B>` I get `Bar<T>` and not `Bar<B>`

Solution (thanks to @LouisWasserman): use Foo.class.getGeenricInterfaces()[0].getActualTypeParameters() returns the correct TypeVariable (B instead of T, in the previous example)

Comment: How will you use this?

Comment: How are you going about calling getGenericInterfaces to Foo<A, B>?

Comment: I'm developing a static analyzer and I need to properly map type relationships in order to perform type unification; i.e. I would like to know programmatically asses that Bar<String> is a supertype of Foo<Integer,String>. I would like to reason about types without instantiating concrete types, and for this I need to get the mapping before

Comment: @LouisWasserman using getGenericIntergaces I get access to Bar<T> and I don't know how to test if T~B or T~A

Comment: @FrancescoBellomi: That doesn't answer my question; I wanted to see the code you were using to call `getGenericInterfaces`.  In particular I want to know how you're calling `getGenericInterfaces` on `Foo<A, B>` instead of a raw `Foo.class`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman you're right. I was using `Foo.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0].getRawType().getGenericTypes()`. Using `Foo.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0].getActualTypeArguments()` brings `Bar<B>` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

well using `TypeVariable#getName()` return the type as it appears in the source code in your case it's normal to get `Bar<T>`. [TypeVariable Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html)

Using reflection in generic Classes can't help, because of Type Erasure. [Erasure of Generic Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)

I've the same issue in some personal projects, I tried to change the design of my class, have a look at the example below:

Instead of this:

```
public class Mapper<T> {

   public Mapper(){
   }
}
```

I used this:

```
public class Mapper {
   private Class<?> entityClazz;
   public Mapper(Class<?> entity){
       this.entityClazz = entity
       //Here I've donne all reflection issues i want ! 
   }
}
```

You can use `Class#isAssignableFrom()` [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) to test assignability between Class Objects.
I hope this helps, good luck !